# Complex Numbers union of balls

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $a\in \mathbb{C}$. Then $\bigcup_{R>0} B(a,R)=\mathbb{C}$

Proof: Let $x\in \mathbb{C}$. Let $|x-a|=M$ for some $M\geq 0$. Then observe that $|x-a|<M+1$ and so $x\in B(a,M+1)$.

I've been told that this proof is incorrect, I don't see why it is, may someone clarify?

Comment: To be clear.  You are trying to prove the first line, and your proof is the second line?

Comment: @NazimJ yup, i''l clarify this now.

Comment: I don't see any problem

Comment: The proof looks correct to me. The only nitpick I can see is that you proved $\mathbb{C} \subset \bigcup_{R > 0}B(a, R)$, and you need to show the reverse inclusion to conclude that there is equality. But this reverse inclusion is quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not complete because you ignore one direction.  And you could always be more explicit about some details it doesn't hurt. Ie both directions are:

Clearly, $\cup_{R>0} B(a,R) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$

To show that $\mathbb{C} \subseteq \cup_{R>0} B(a,R)$, **same proof as you give**.  Therefore, $x \in B(a,M+1) \subseteq \cup_{R>0} B(a,R)$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{C} = \cup_{R>0} B(a,R)$

Comment: So the sentiment is the proof is correct, just incomplete by skipping some "obvious" statements